# PHP prepare statement

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I don't understand why this code isn't working. I get this error:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement.

I have seen few examples. According to examples it should work.

```
$password = generatePassword();
$passwordHash = hash('sha512', $password);
$random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));

$passwordHashSalt = hash('sha512', $passwordHash . $random_salt);
$sqlStatement = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE members (password, salt) VALUES (?, ?)  WHERE username = ?');
$statement->bind_param('sss', $passwordHashSalt, $random_salt, $username);
```

Comment: `$statement` !== `$sqlStatement`

Comment: Thanky you! I don't know how can't I see that stupidity.

Answer (score -1):

Your bind param is missing the last string param. Even if it is the same var you must list it again.

`$statement->bind_param('sss', $passwordHashSalt, $random_sal, {$otherVarName})`

EDIT:
Now that you actually fixed your post
Make sure you address your var names:

$sqlStatement != $statement

Comment: How do you mean address my var names?

Comment: just meant to consistently use the actual var names - in reference to the typo.